# How to generate a permutation given X combination of values

Tags: javascript, algorithm, permutation

So imagine I have the following list of elements

```
4 diferent elements of A : A1 A2 A3 A4
4 different elements of B: B1 B2 B3 B4
4 different elements of C: C1 C2 C3 C4
```

And amongst all those elements, I would need to generate a unique combination of elements for example:

```
A1B1C1 , A1B1C2 , A1B2C3, A2B2C3, A1B1BC1 (this one cant happen since its repeated)
```

How would I generate that given for example

```
A = [A1,A2,A3,A4]
B = [B1,B2,B3,B4]
C = [C1,C2,C3,C4]
```

Comment: "A1B1BC1" is not a combination of A B C.

Comment: What have **YOU** tried / researched so far? Where exactly did you get stuck? Share your ideas / thoughts / findings / code.